# How to stop Excel from holding copied data in that window?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

It's not the best title, but what I am trying to do is:

1. Copy cell from Excel
2. Paste into Chrome, find the needed data on Google
3. Go back to Excel and paste the new data in different cell

What happens is on step 1 Excel keeps dashed line running around the copied cell, so now that I go to step 3 it pastes the same selected cell instead of the data I have copied in step 2.

One solution is to cut/paste the cell from step 1 just to get rid of the dashed line.

Comment: And pressing ESC to get rid of the dashed line in between is not an option?

Comment: @mtak, I didn't know I could press ESC. But still, is there any other option to do that automatically?

Comment: Excel would normally removed the dashed line if the clipboard contents had been changed - are you sure that it is copying OK from Chrome? e.g. try pasting it into text editor